# How to format a label in ExtJS to look like a link

Tags: button, extjs, hyperlink

How can a label be formatted to have look of a link in extjs?
I don't want to have link functionality (to go to specific href). I would like just to have classical button which looks like a link and have click listeners.

I've tried with the following code:

```
{
  xtype: 'box',
  autoEl: {tag: 'a', href: 'http://www.google.com', html: 'Google'}
}
```

but, this is classical link.

I also tried

```
{
xtype: 'box',
html: '<a href="" class="link-forgot-password"> Forgot Password ?/a>'
}
```

That looks fine, but what is missing is listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'box',
    html: '<a href="#" class="link-forgot-password"> Forgot Password ?/a>',
    listeners: {
        el: {
            click: function () {
                console.log('click');
            },
            scope: this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arthur. The problem is that it really fires click event, but after that it reloads my application. That's why I put href="". How can I prevent it?

Comment: <a href='#'... <--- use this to avoid reloading of the page. I have edited the sample.

Comment: Have a look at the xtemplates in extjs.

Comment: I don't know, I have not seen your code. Provide some fiddle sample in separate thread.

Comment: It is another problem, open new "question" please.